# How to compute the residue of $\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1}$ around $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, singularity

Here is a problem in my complex analysis notes, i.e. compute the residue of $\frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{z}}-1}$ around $z=0$. I think that this isolated singularity is an essential singularity. The problem is to find the Laurent expansion of it near $z=0$. But the difficulty here is that I can't use those formulas such as $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ since here the variable doesn't tend to zero.

Can anyone give me some suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

That cannot be done, since $0$ is *not* an isolated singularity of your function. This follows from the fact that, if $f(z)=\dfrac1{e^{1/z}-1}$, then every point of the form $\dfrac1{2n\pi i}$ ($n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$) is an isolated singularity of $f$.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realize this! Thank you very much!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.